# change status on or off when user log out in php

Tags: php

i have some problem on my code, i'm confused how i set up logic on my code.
i want to ask for this problem, how to set status on user account every time they're clicked log out and change status to 'off'.

this my code :

```
<?php
  session_start();

  include_once "config/db.php";

  $params = session_get_cookie_params();

  setcookie(session_name(), null, time()-48000,
            $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['httponly']);

  session_destroy();

  $sql = "UPDATE user SET status 'off' WHERE user_id={$_SESSION['u_id']}";
  mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

  mysqli_close($connect);

  header("location: login.php");
  exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your order first you have to update query then destroy cookie and session

```
<?php
  session_start();

  include_once "config/db.php";

  $params = session_get_cookie_params();  

  $sql = "UPDATE user SET status = 'off' WHERE user_id={$_SESSION['u_id']}";
  mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

  mysqli_close($connect);

  setcookie(session_name(), null, time()-48000,
            $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['httponly']);

  session_destroy();

  header("location: login.php");
  exit();

?>
```

Comment: One more thing, his update statement is not correct.. `status = 'off'` instead of `status 'off'`. And he should use prepared statements. I hope you will update your answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Before you destroy your session write your update query

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET status =  'off' WHERE user_id={$_SESSION['u_id']}";

session_destroy();
```